# jHipster registry can't compile angular dependencies

Tags: angular, jhipster

So I cloned the jHipster registries, but am getting the following warnings:

```
npm WARN angular2-cookie@1.2.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-cookie@1.2.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-translate@4.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-translate@4.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
```

How do I fix this so I can build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it's an Angular project, after cloning the jhipster-registry project, you need to:

- `yarn install` (to install all dependencies) or `npm install`, depending which tool you use
- then you can start the registry: `./mvnw`

Another solution:

- you can download directly the war package at https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/releases/download/v3.0.1/jhipster-registry-3.0.1.war
- then, use `java -Djhipster.security.authentication.jwt.secret=xxxx -jar jhipster-registry-3.0.1.war`

Comment: Pascal, it's not the first question about this, maybe we should add these instructions to the README.

Comment: Yes totally agree

Comment: Pascal, sorry for crossposting with github; you're right I should not have done it that way. Thanks for your response.

Comment: no problem. if it's not clear, that means we need to improve our docs and we will do it